# String to Int array[] conversion size problem in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

I want the array that is converted from string to int be the size of 8bits or 10 bits.

If I check the size of any of the arrays I have defined above in commas, they give proper size of 8 bits, but when I do that with Key[] array, it shows the size of the array is 1.

I need it to show 10 or 8 since my input is going to be either 1011010100 or 10101010.

Input needs to come from the user. I cannot hardcode it.

```
import java.util.*;

public class S_DES {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

                // First we define the S-DES functions:
                int[] IP = { 2, 6, 3, 1, 4, 8, 5, 7 };
                int[] IP_Inverse = { 4, 1, 3, 5, 7, 2, 8, 6 };
                int[] P10 = { 3, 5, 2, 7, 4, 10, 1, 9, 8, 6 };
                int[] P8 = { 6, 3, 7, 4, 8, 5, 10, 9 };
                int[] EP = { 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 1 };
                int[] P4 = { 2, 4, 3, 1 };
                int[][] S0 = { { 1, 0, 3, 2 }, { 3, 2, 1, 0 }, { 0, 2, 1, 3 }, { 3, 1, 3, 2 } };
                int[][] S1 = { { 0, 1, 2, 3 }, { 2, 0, 1, 3 }, { 3, 0, 1, 0 }, { 2, 1, 0, 3 } };

                /* DESCRIPTION:
                 * Now we => take string input from user => validate it => convert in into an integer array and  => put it through the
                 * P10 function as defined in S-DES functions
                 */

                System.out.println("Please enter the 10 bit binary key: ");
                String str = input.next(); //get user input for key in string form
                String[] arrayStr = str.split(","); // convert string input into an array separated by commas
                int size = arrayStr.length;   // calculate the size of the array
                int[] Key = new int[size];    // Create a new array of the size of the string
                for (int i=0; i<size; i++){   // convert the string key array into integer array
                        Key[i]  = Integer.parseInt(arrayStr[i]);
                        System.out.println(Key);
                }
                int key_size = Key.length;
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Key) + "\t You Key[] array size is" + key_size);                

        }
}
```

Comment: Fix your formatting.

Comment: Step through your program with the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

you input some text like this : `1,0,0...` the code can run well

```
String[] arrayStr = str.split(",");
```

but if you input `1011010100`, the arrayStr is array like this `{"1011010100"}` just one element

---

if you want parse `1011010100` can use `String.toCharArray` get char array and for-loop using `Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(char))` to set